# Python - while loop semi works depending on where i start on the menu

Tags: python, while-loop

i am a super beginner to python.
Below is a simple math quiz.  The problem is that selecting option 2 (subtraction) then 1 (addition) shuts down the program instead of asking addition problem.
It works from 1 to 2 but it does not work from 2 to 1.  Do you guys know what i am missing here? Thanks in advance.

```
while user_input == 1:
    num1 = (random.randrange(0,100))
    num2 = (random.randrange(0,100))
    answer = num1 + num2
    problem = str(num1) + " + " + str(num2)
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    if result == answer:
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('Incorrect')
    user_input = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
```

## subtraction for choice 2

```
while user_input == 2:

    num1 = (random.randrange(0,100))
    num2 = (random.randrange(0,100))
    answer = num1 - num2
    problem = str(num1) + " - " + str(num2)
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    if result == answer:
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('Incorrect')
    user_input = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
```

## Exit for choice 3 - the User is done with the quiz

```
else:
    print('See you again')
```

Comment: What is the purpose of last `else` in _choice 3_. And it is without an `if` statement.

Comment: I normally would never say this, but this problem would probably most appropriately be posted with code in a large block rather than separated as it seems to be a control flow issue.

Comment: you can have an else after a loop. That executes after the loop ends

Answer (score 0):

For good practice and readability, I would implement something like:

```
choice = input()
while choice != -1:
    choice = input()
    if choice == 1:
        #do something
    else if choice == 2:
        #do something else
    else if choice == -1:
        print("bye")
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong. You must do something like this:

```
   choice = input()

    while choice == "1" or choice == "2":
              if choice == "1":
                  #do add
              else:
                 #do subtraction
              choice = input()

   print("bye")
```

Comment: Your else still does not have an if statement attached. In addition, this is bad practice to need to accept all possible forms of input as conditionals to keep the loop going rather than having another 'exit' value

Comment: I apologize. It seems that an else: attached to a while loop has some interesting failure of loop behavior. It does not need an if attached and may actually work how you had it written. However, if this is what you intended, I still disagree with the practice for the OP who is on a more beginner level.

Comment: wow thank you for all your help.  I will digest this now and probably get back to you guys in a few.